# Getting error - InvalidUseOfMatchersException in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method below:

```
public Response getAbcExample(Double a, Double b, Integer c, String d, RequestHeader requestHeader)
            throws Exception  {
        Map<String, String> logMap = new HashMap<>();
        Response response = new Response();
        String jsonString = _getAB_Exampe(a, b, c, requestHeader);
    }
```

My mockito method is below

```
@Test
public void getabc_Example_Success() throws IOException{
    Response response=new Response();
    RequestHeader requestHeaders=new RequestHeader();
    response.setMessage("Success");
    response.setStatusCode("200");          
when(abc.getabc_Example_Success(anyDouble(),anyDouble(),anyInt(),anyString(),requestHeaders)).thenReturn(response);
        Mockito.verify(abc,Mockito.times(1)).getabcExable(Mockito.any(Double.class),Mockito.any(Double.class),Mockito.any(Integer.class),Mockito.eq(""),Mockito.any(RequestHeader.class));      
  }
```

but am getting:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException.

whether my code is correct to test the actual method or i need to change?. I want cover the test cased all the lines.

Comment: `requestHeaders` is no valid matcher for your `when` call. So, do what the exception message suggests to you.

Comment: i tried below doNothing().when(abc).getAbcExample(Mockito.any(Double.class),Mockito.any(Double.class),Mockito.any(Integer.class),Mockito.eq(""),Mockito.any(RequestHeader.class)); but getting MockitoException and only void method use doNothing

Answer (score 2):

I did some test based on your code and here are some insights..

**1)** You do not need to use the doReturn().when().. syntax.. In your case the when().thenReturn() is fine (although you still can stick to the other version, up to you).

**2)** Not sure how do you instantiate the `'abc'`object.. but it has to be a `@Mock` or a `@Spy`, otherwise you cannot use the when().thenReturn() feature on it.

**3)** In the when().. you are using the any() in combination with a real object without a matcher (the requstHeaders object):

```
when(abc.getabc_Example_Success(anyDouble(),anyDouble()
            ,anyInt(),anyString(),requestHeaders));
```

You cannot do that and Mockito would throw an error:

```
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

You have make it either `Mockito.any(RequestHeaders.class)` or `Mockito.eq(requestHeaders)`

**Working Solution**

So based on the above your test class should look more or less like the following:

```
@Spy
private Abc abc;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void tst() throws Exception{
        Response response= mock(Response.class);
        RequestHeader requestHeaders=mock(RequestHeader.class);
        when(a.getAbcExample(anyDouble(),anyDouble(),anyInt()
        ,anyString(),Mockito.eq(requestHeaders))).thenReturn(response);

        abc.getAbcExample(1.0, 1.0, 1, "", requestHeaders); // invoke the mocked method

        verify(a, times(1)).getAbcExample(Mockito.any(Double.class)
                 ,Mockito.any(Double.class),Mockito.any(Integer.class)
                 ,Mockito.eq(""),Mockito.any(RequestHeader.class));


    }
}
```

Alternatively:

- You can use @Mock instead of @Spy
- The last param in the `verify`.. `Mockito.any(RequestHeader.class)`. This can be replaced for the actual `requestHeaders` object and still will work.

Try it out.

Comment: most probably only item 3 is the real issue.